# Intellij never suggest Java libraries

Tags: intellij-idea

I was trying to use List and Set on my code using Intellij.
But Intellij only suggest classes under maven libraries, not JDK.

[image]

I can only use Java Collections(List, Set) by manually typing imports on the top of the file. so inconvenient.. please help

Comment: Make sure JDK is configured correctly for the project. Try to remove and then add JSDK again. You can also try File | Invalidate Caches and Restart,

Comment: @CrazyCoder - -thank you.. Invalidate Caches and Restart works :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that Project SDK is set:

1. Open Project Structure `File` -> `Project Structure...`
2. `Project Settings` -> `Project`
3. Verify that you have a `Project SDK` set up.

Alternatively, try and create a simple Java Application and see if the problem persists. Then, try to re-import the maven project.

Hope this helps :)