# IntelliJ intellisense never suggest java.utils.Map

Tags: intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ 17.2.5. The problem I am facing is that it's intellisense never suggest or import `java.utils.Map` on itself.

[image]

I always have to import it manually by typing the import statement. Although it suggest all other classes in `java.utils` package like `List`, `HashMap` and others. So I suppose that this is not class path issue.

I know that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160405/intellij-never-suggest-java-libraries) but that is not my case and the solution there is not working for me.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade your IntelliJ, I use `2017.3` and can't reproduce what you see. It correctly suggests `java.util.Map<K, V>` first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report in IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker, and even then it should a bug report only after the latest IDEA (community edition is free) is checked for reproduction.